# Argument of type 'true' is not assignable to parameter of type

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I have typescript code

Here is it

```
$('.Switch').on('click', function() {
if ($(this).hasClass('On')) {
  $(this).parent().find('input:checkbox').attr('checked', true);
  $(this).removeClass('On').addClass('Off');
  $(this).parent().find('input:hidden').val(0);
  $(".filter_stops").each(function() {
    if ($(this).slider( "option", "value" ) === 0) {
      $(this).off('slidechange');
      $(this).slider( "option", "value", 99 );
      $(`#stops_${this.id.split('_')[1]}`).val(`Max ${$( this ).slider("value")} ${__('byten')}`);
      $(`#filter_stops_${this.id.split('_')[1]}`).val($( this ).slider("value"));
      $(this).on('slidechange', FilterFunctions.onFilterChange);
    }
  });
```

In this code I have 2 errors

In this row `$(this).parent().find('input:checkbox').attr('checked', true);` I have

> Argument of type 'true' is not assignable to parameter of type '(index: number, attr: string) => string | number'.

And in this

```
 $(`#stops_${this.id.split('_')[1]}`).val(`Max ${$( this ).slider("value")} ${__('byten')}`);
```

> Property 'id' does not exist on type 'TElement'.

How I can fix it?

Comment: please share your html code

Comment: use `$(this).parent().find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', true);`  instead of `$(this).parent().find('input:checkbox').attr('checked', true);`

Comment: Yes. It fixed first error. But What I can do with second?@SupunFictionPraneeth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case, use:

```
$(this).parent().find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', true);
```

Because using `attr` you get only the initial value of the attribute, if set. `prop` gives the current value of the property.

For the second case, use:

```
$(this).attr('id').
```

or

```
this.getAttribute('id')
```

instead of

```
this.id
```

Hope this serves you.

Comment: If I use `this.attr('id').`I have`Property 'attr' does not exist on type 'TElement'.`

Comment: My mistake. I corrrected it. You've got two options, one with jQuery and one without

Comment: Seems it helps. Thank's